# Проверочное слово к «претерпевать»

Tags: орфография

Слово претерпевать... Отвечает на "что делать?". В проверочное ему сопоставляют слово в неопределенной форме претерпеть. Отвечает на "что сделать?". Но это не начальная ФОРМА слова, ведь изменилось спряжение, а значит не является проверочным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверочным является любое однокоренное слово, в котором «сомнительный» звук стоит под ударением. «Претерпевать» и «претерпеть», очевидно, одного корня. Вид глагола тут совершенно ни при чем.